# Dates before 1970

Tags: date, livecode, seconds

Could anyone please tell me why Livecode does not convert years before 1970 to seconds?

This works:

```
on mouseUp
   put "March 14, 1970" into tDate
   convert tDate to seconds
   put tDate
end mouseUp
```

but this doesn't work:

```
on mouseUp
   put "March 14, 1961" into tDate
   convert tDate to seconds
   put tDate
end mouseUp
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because it uses the Unix Time Stamp. The Unix Time Stamp counts up every second, since the **1st of January 1970**. So, dates before 1970 can't be displayed. On this website, you can get the live Unix Time Stamp and learn more about it: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Regards

Comment: Many systems correctly support negative Unix timestamps. If LiveCode does not, perhaps that should be reported as a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Which version of Livecode are you using?
I tried your sample script

```
on mouseUp
   put "March 14, 1961" into tDate
   convert tDate to seconds
   put tDate
end mouseUp
```

in Livecode 10DP4 and 9.6.8 on macOS. Both versions returned -25318800